# Is it possible to overlay actual points on top of a ListPlot3D?

Tags: plotting

Hopefully this is a quick and easy question, I just couldn't find anything in the documentation that seems like what I want to do.

I have the 3D dataset below, and many others like it. The issue is that I have only a small number of points and a big gap in the data on the Y-axis and so the ListPlot3D is somewhat confusing to look at, and the ListPointPlot3D is worthless because its hard to see where points are in relation to each other. Is it possible to overlay the actual data points (As noticeable points of a different color) on top of the surface generated by ListPlot3D?

```
data:= {
    {0.100000, 0.000100, 1.258800}, 
    {0.100000, 0.001000, 1.279900}, 
    {1.000000, 0.010000, 1.224200}, 
    {0.400000, 0.000100, 1.283200}, 
    {0.700000, 0.010000, 1.224900}, 
    {0.700000, 0.001000, 1.240000}, 
    {0.400000, 0.010000, 1.307400}, 
    {0.700000, 0.000100, 1.193900}, 
    {1.000000, 0.000100, 1.248700}, 
    {1.000000, 0.001000, 1.176900}, 
    {0.400000, 0.001000, 1.244800}, 
    {0.100000, 0.010000, 1.334600}
}
VariableLRPlot := ListPlot3D[data, PlotRange -> {{0.100000, 1.000000}, {0.000100, 0.010000}, {1.1769, 1.3346}}, AxesLabel->{"MaxLearningRate", "MinLearningRate", "AllDataTestError"}] 
VariableLRPlot
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Show[

 ListPlot3D[data,
  ImageSize -> 600,
  PlotRange -> {{0.100000, 1.000000}, {0.000100, 0.010000}, {1.1769, 1.3346}},
  PlotStyle -> Opacity@0.5,
  AxesLabel -> {"MaxLearningRate", "MinLearningRate", "AllDataTestError"}],

 Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[0.02], Point /@ data}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect Thanks!

Comment: No need to map, `Point[data]` works nicely.

Comment: @J.M. And `Point[data]` gives better render performance than `Point/@data`.